# Dependency conflict during install of openssl-devel

Tags: qt, openssl, fedora

My Fedora's kernel version - 4.1.13-100.fc21.

I am trying to install developer libraries for OpenSSL by enternig command:

```
sudo yum install openssl-devel
```

It gives output:

```
Error: Packet: pcre-devel-8.35-14.fc21.x86_64 (updates)
          Requires: pcre(x86-64) = 8.35-14.fc21
          Installed: pcre-8.35-17.fc21.x86_64 (@updates-testing)
              pcre(x86-64) = 8.35-17.fc21
          Available: pcre-8.35-7.fc21.x86_64 (fedora)
              pcre(x86-64) = 8.35-7.fc21
          Available: pcre-8.35-14.fc21.x86_64 (updates)
              pcre(x86-64) = 8.35-14.fc21
```

Another option bellow is to use --skip-broken to overcome this problem. Entering:

```
sudo yum install openssl-devel --skip-broken
```

Provides output that packets were missed due to problems with dependencies:

```
krb5-devel-1.12.2-9.fc21.x86_64 from fedora
krb5-devel-1.12.2-19.fc21.x86_64 from updates
libselinux-devel-2.3-5.fc21.x86_64 from fedora
libselinux-devel-2.3-10.fc21.x86_64 from updates
1:openssl-devel-1.0.1k-12.fc21.x86_64 from updates
pcre-devel-8.35-7.fc21.x86_64 from fedora
pcre-devel-8.35-14.fc21.x86_64 from updates
```

What can I do? The very beginning of this problem is error in Qt about missing header files from openssl folder.

Comment: Fedora 21 is EOL. You should update to some supported release.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution on myself. First I needed to downgrade prce using dnf:

```
sudo dnf downgrade pcre-devel-8.35-7.fc21
```

Then I have both versions of pcre on my computer. Running these two comments helped:

```
rpm --rebuilddb
dnf distro-sync
```

And in the last step I was able to install openssl-devel and all dependencies without problem by entering:

```
sudo dnf install openssl-devel
```